# image_transport republish theora core dump on startup

Tags: image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with Groovy. I am trying to republish a theora stream as decompressed images using:

```
rosrun image_transport republish theora in:=camera/image raw out:=camera/image_decompressed
```

The node core dumps on startup with the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'image_transport::TransportLoadException'
  what():  Unable to load plugin for transport 'theora', error string:
Failed to load library /opt/ros/groovy/lib//libtheora_image_transport.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /opt/ros/groovy/lib//libtheora_image_transport.so: undefined symbol: th_comment_clear)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I run the node republishing compressed or raw streams, the node starts and functions normally.

I see theora as a valid image transport using `rosrun image_transport list_transports`. I get this same error on 3 different machines all running Groovy, and the error does not happen using Fuerte. Could this be an issue with how image_transport_plugins is compiled?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56544/image_transport-republish-theora-core-dump-on-startup/) by [bgoldfai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2600/bgoldfai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

this bug should be fixed in:
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/commit/cec427bcd93ba941bd622389b10934811b2da70c

In future, please create an issue directly on github for bugs like this:
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins

Cheers,
Julius

---

Originally posted by [jkammerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3073/jkammerl/) with karma: 146 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-19**:
Hi jkammerl, I installed 1.8.20 theora_image_transport on my laptop, but when I run "rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw theora", I got the new warning "[theora] Packet was not a Theora header" and it seems theora doesn't work at all because the video streaming is very laggy.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-19**:
After I installed the total image_transport_plugin stack instead of only theora_image_transport package, image_view can accept theora image. But there is another problem, when I try to republish theora image to raw image, "[theora] Packet was not a Theora header" appears again.

**Comment by [jkammerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3073/jkammerl/) on 2013-03-19**:
There is a general flaw here. The libtheora encoder uses the OGG container format which is not designed to be used for streaming at all. The stream starts with the first ROS subscriber and it starts streaming the header followed by the video data.Accordingly,a second subscriber will miss the header!

**Comment by [jkammerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3073/jkammerl/) on 2013-03-19**:
see: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/issues/4

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-22**:
Hi jkammerl, do you have plan to develop new fashionable encoder like vp8?